# Do non-EU passport holders in Ireland get very short validity schengen visas?

Tags: schengen

From what I've noticed, non-EU people from Ireland applying for Schengen visas will only get very short validity visas. My friends who applied in France, Netherlands and Italy only get 15 days to 2 months validity visas. I received my visa today from France and they gave only 7 days, which was the duration of my trip. I asked for a multiple-entry visa and they gave me a single entry. I was really disappointed. Could somebody shed some light on this?

Comment: Do you have any evidence to support your belief that "non-EU people from the UK always get 6-months or 1-year visas"?

Comment: “...non-EU people from UK always get a 6 months or 1 year validity visas.” How do you know that? What justification did you provide for a multiple entry visa (other than “I want one”)? Is this your first Schengen visa? It’s far more likely that you’ll get a single entry visa reflecting the trip you stated you intend to make, if so.

Comment: I have lots of friends in the UK who applied for their first schengen visa and they all got 1 year validity.

Comment: I am afraid to apply again in January. I dont want to be disappointed again of getting a single entry 1 week visa.

Comment: I think it's pretty hard to assess the denials when we don't know the citizenship(s) and complete application details for your friends. And even if we did know those things, the number of your friends will be a pretty small sample number compared to the number of Schengen visas sought overall. A conclusion based on this sample is therefore likely to be wrong.

Comment: @anonIreland You may have been disappointed by a single entry visa, but it could have been worse - your application could have been refused.

Comment: The decision could also have been related to the expiry date of your residence permit, per your most recent question https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/17841/will-my-schengen-visa-application-automatically-be-denied-if-my-resident-permit

Answer (score 1):

A short validity visa for first-time applicant is the rule, rather than an exception. In principle, you're only supposed to get a visa covering the specific trip you describe in your application unless you have a track record of repeated travel to the Schengen area and specific reasons to make regular trips (e.g. professional reasons). From that perspective, the visas you describe aren't especially short.

Now, I have also heard anecdotal evidence that UK residents occasionally get longer visas, sometimes even on their first application and without asking specifically. I don't know how common that is or why it doesn't seem apply to Ireland but that's an exception rather than the rule.